# Find borders on a list in python

Tags: python

A list of points is given (found by pathing algorithm), and I'm interested in the enter/exit points into the domain. Points outside the domain are listed as `None`. An example path would be `[None, 1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5, None]`, the result for this should be `[(1,2), (3,5)]`. Now for the edge case `[1, 2, None]`, the result should be `[(None, 2)]`, for the mirror case `[None, 1, 2]`, it should be `[(1, None)]`.

Without the last two additions, I've got

```
[(systems[0], systems[-1]) if not outside else None
 for outside, systems in [(o, list(sys))
 for o, sys in groupby(path, lambda x: x is None)]]
```

or [via IRC](http://bpaste.net/show/3QuQZdU7FHhIQurLDtiN/):

```
def find_borders(L):
    it = iter(L)
    for item in it:
        if item is None:
            continue
        start = item
        end = item
        for item in it:
            if item is None:
                break
            end = item
        yield (start, end)
```

For the solution via IRC, adding the `None` at the start is easy, but basically impossible at the end without a `peek` on `iter`.

How do I implement the second edge case `[None, 1,2]` => `[(1, None)]`?

I created a solution that should work, but doesn't. It gives me an
`IndexError` because `systems` is an empty list, which shouldn't
happen because `groupby` guarantees it does not group into an empty list.

```
def find_borders(path):
    grouped = list(groupby(path, lambda x: x is None))
    for index, (o, sys) in enumerate(grouped):
        systems = list(sys)
        if index == 0:
            yield (None, systems[-1])
        elif index == len(grouped)-1:
            yield (systems[0], None)
        else:
            yield (systems[0], systems[-1])
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @TimCastelijns as edited, is it possible to implement the edge cases in the current code?

Comment: At the moment you check if item is None, can't you check if you're at the end of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tests = [
    [None, 1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5, None],
    [1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5, None],
    [None,1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 2, None],
    [None, 1, 2],
]

def find_borders(L):
    it = iter(L)

    start_none = False

    for item in it:
        if item is None:
            start_none = True
            continue
        if start_none:
            start = item
        else:
            start = None

        end = item

        end_none = False

        for item in it:
            if item is None:
                end_none = True
                break
            end = item
        if not end_none:
            end = None
        yield (start, end)

        start_none = True

for t in tests:
    print
    print t
    for x in find_borders(t):
        print x
```

Results

```
[None, 1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5, None]
(1, 2)
(3, 5)

[1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5, None]
(None, 2)
(3, 5)

[None, 1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5]
(1, 2)
(3, None)

[1, 2, None, 3, 4, 5]
(None, 2)
(3, None)

[1, 2, None]
(None, 2)

[None, 1, 2]
(1, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant:

```
def find_borders(L):
    entries = []
    exits = []
    if L[0] is not None:
        entries.append(None)

    for i in range(len(L[:-2])):
        if L[i] is None:
            entries.append(L[i+1])
        if L[i+2] is None:
            exits.append(L[i+1])

    if L[-1] is not None:
        exits.append(None)
    return zip(entries, exits)
```